# How to specify start time in a python matplotlib animation?

Tags: python, matplotlib, matplotlib-animation

I am animating a time series that has 3600 timesteps. I only want to plot timestep 1200 to 1800 in an animation, however I can only get the animation to run from the very first time step onwards. Below is a simplified version of what I've been trying.

```
sal = ax1.contourf(X[:,:,1200],Y[:,:,1200],Z[:,:,1200]),100)

def animate(i):
    sal = ax1.contourf(X[:,:,i],Y[:,:,i],Z[:,:,i]),100)

anim = FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=100, frames=len(Seconds[1200:1800]))
```

The above still starts from 0.
I want to be able to specify a starting index of 1200 not 0.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`len(Seconds[1200:1800])` returns gives a single value `600`, and according to the [docs](https://matplotlib.org/stable/api/_as_gen/matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation.html#matplotlib.animation.FuncAnimation) passing an `int` to `frames` is the same passing `range(x)`. So I think your just animating just the first 600 frames. Try

```
anim = FuncAnimation(f, animate, interval=100, frames=range(1200,1800))
```

and let me know if it works!